# Why PUN is not giving callbacks? ProtonNetworking is not working as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to make simple steps with PUN, just connect to master server, and join random room.
I have setted log all info to console, and as I understand I am connectin to server, but OnConnectedToMaster is never called.

```
 using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
     using Photon;
 public class  RandomMatchmakera : Photon.PunBehaviour {

/// <summary>
/// MonoBehaviour method called on GameObject by Unity during early initialization phase.
/// </summary>
void Avake(){
    // this makes sure we can use PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel() on the master client and all clients in the same room sync their level automatically
    PhotonNetwork.automaticallySyncScene = true;


}

void Start(){
    // the following line checks if this client was just created (and not yet online). if so, we connect
    if (PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed == ClientState.PeerCreated)
    {
        Debug.Log ("connecting");
        // Connect to the photon master-server. We use the settings saved in PhotonServerSettings (a .asset file in this project)
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings("0.9");
    }
}

public void OnJoinedLobby()
{
    Debug.Log("DemoAnimator/Launcher: OnJoinedLobby() was called by PUN");
    PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
}
public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
{
    Debug.Log("DemoAnimator/Launcher: OnConnectedToMaster() was called by PUN");
    PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
}

public override void OnDisconnectedFromPhoton()
{

    Debug.LogWarning("DemoAnimator/Launcher: OnDisconnectedFromPhoton() was called by PUN");        
}

public override void OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed(object[] codeAndMsg){
    Debug.LogWarning("DemoAnimator/Launcher: Failing joining random room");
    PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom (null, new RoomOptions (){ MaxPlayers = 4 }, null);
}
public override void OnJoinedRoom(){
    Debug.LogWarning("DemoAnimator/Launcher: Joined room");
}


public void OnFailedToConnectToPhoton(object parameters)
{
    Debug.Log("OnFailedToConnectToPhoton. StatusCode: " + parameters + " ServerAddress: " + PhotonNetwork.ServerAddress);
}
}
```

Here are going loggs.

[Firstlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6DWS.png)

[Secondlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJlp5.png)

Comment: If i am not mistaken PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings() is to be used when you self host Photon. Edit: It looks like you successfully passed Operation 230 (Authentication) and received your unique ID from server. Moreover, you accessed the GameServer too. I dont see a problem

Comment: As i understand from documentation this function connects to the Photon Cloud, if you want connetc to own host you have to use ConnectToMaster()
The problem is what i am not getting callback OnConnectedToMaster

Comment: Could you please delete   if (PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed == ClientState.PeerCreated) and try again

Comment: Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have just copy pasted your solution and it is successfully being called.Assuming you are using PhotonTutorials from PUN asset and Marco Polo example I think you have not referenced RandomMatchmakera script from your project.[image: Here is how you do it]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help someone. For me the problem was with my region. I had selected my region to none instead of specifying it to a particular region. Therefore locate the

> PhotonServerSettings

file and change the region to something specific e.g EU, Kr etc